# Can this javascript be made unobtrusive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this inline javascript, is there any way it could be made unobtrusive? thanks.

```
<a href="/uploads/status/image/52/Zombatar_1.jpg" onclick="displayLightBox(this); return false;">
    <img alt="Thumb_zombatar_1" src="/uploads/status/image/52/thumb_Zombatar_1.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: Of course, add a click handler and prevent the default handler from running.

Comment: What purpose does `false;;` have? Seems like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Why do you think it's obtrusive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, I'll give you a jQuery answer. Your `a` element currently has no identifying characteristic other than its `href` attribute. It would be easiest to give it an `id` and then use an `id` selector. The key is simply find some characteristic by which you can identify the element you want to target.

If an `id` or a `class` is not an option, use an attribute selector:

```
$("a[href='/uploads/status/image/52/Zombatar_1.jpg']").click(function() {
    displayLightBox(this);
    return false;
});
```

Notice that I've removed the random `false;;` from your inline event handler as as far as I can tell it serves no purpose whatsoever.

**Update** (see comments)

As you have multiple elements to bind the event handler to, your best bet will probably be a common class. You can then use a class selector:

```
$(".myLink").click(function() {
    displayLightBox(this);
    return false;
});
```

The `click` event handler is bound to all elements in the matched set. When it executes, `this` refers to the clicked element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply James, the problem is I may have multiple links of this type generated dynamically on a page. How would I go about targeting them uniquely when i could have one, or possibly 10?

Comment: @pingu - Give them all a common `class` name. You can then select all of them with a class selector, for example `$(".linkclass")`. Inside the `click` event handler, `this` refers to the clicked element, so you only need the short snippet shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a good idea to keep your HTML markup and JavaScript code separate. I would recommend applying the onClick behavior to the link after it has been rendered. In my example, I use jQuery to bind the event handler function to the link:

```
$('#element_id').click(function() {
    displayLightBox(this);
    return false;
});
```

If you're writing large web applications, separating your business logic and presentation is essential for writing maintainable and supportable code.

Your jQuery selector will vary depending on how it's placed on the page. If you could provide the HTML context in which that link is created, I can provide a better suited jQuery selector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Elliot, the link is wrapped in a <div class="status"> and is one one of potentially many statuses in my "content" div.

Comment: In that case, and assuming you want all the links to have the same click behavior, I would use this jQuery selector: $('div.status a').click(function() { //same as before });

Comment: You could decouple even further by using `.on()` with delegation syntax and delegate listening to a common ancestor. You would, of course, use classes (or other more generic selectors) instead of ID.